# How do I assign points/score based on word detection in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, detection

im new to python and trying to learn word detection. I have a dataframe with words

```
sharina['transcript']
Out[25]: 
0      thank you for calling my name is Tiffany and we want to let you know this call is recorded...
1                                                Maggie 
2                                  through the time 
3      that you can find I have a question about a claim and our contact is..
4                       three to like even your box box and thank you for your help...
```

I have created an app that detects words from this:

```
def search_multiple_strings_in_file(file_name, list_of_strings):
    """Get line from the file along with line numbers, which contains any string from the list"""
    line_number = 0
    list_of_results = []
    # Open the file in read only mode
    with open("sharina.csv", 'r') as read_obj:
        # Read all lines in the file one by one
        for line in read_obj:
            line_number += 1
            # For each line, check if line contains any string from the list of strings
            for string_to_search in list_of_strings:
                if string_to_search in line:
                    # If any string is found in line, then append that line along with line number in list
                    list_of_results.append((string_to_search, line_number, line.rstrip()))
 
    # Return list of tuples containing matched string, line numbers and lines where string is found
    return list_of_results

# search for given strings in the file 'sample.txt'

matched_lines = search_multiple_strings_in_file('sharina.csv', ['recorded','thank'])
 
print('Total Matched lines : ', len(matched_lines))
for elem in matched_lines:
    print('Word = ', elem[0], ' :: Line Number = ', elem[1], ' :: Line = ', elem[2])
```

I want to assign a score if certain words are detected in the dataframe, for example

if the word 'recorded' has been mentioned = 7 points
if the word 'thank' has been mentioned = 5 points

and then the output gives the summation of the total points/score = 12 in this case. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention that you already have a DataFrame:

This can be done relatively simply with `Series.str.extractall`. First, we create the capturing group, which is a `'|'.join` of all the words, sandwiched between parentheses. This allows you to grab all of the desired words in one Series, with the index of that Series indicative of the row it belonged to. There is also a 'match' index level of that Series that indicates the number of items that matched on that row, not really important in this case.

```
pat = '(' + '|'.join(words) + ')'
#'(recorded|thank)'

df['transcript'].str.extractall(pat)
#                0
#  match          
#0 0         thank     # `'thank'` on line 0
#  1      recorded
#4 0         thank     # `'thank'` also on line 4
```

If you want to assign points, a good organization would be a dict, let the keys be the words, the values be the points. Then you can make the pattern by joining the keys, and get the points by mapping the values:

```
d = {'thank': 5, 'recorded': 7}
pat = '(' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + ')'

df1 = df['transcript'].str.extractall(pat).rename(columns={0: 'word'})
df1['points'] = df1['word'].map(d)
#             word  points
#  match                  
#0 0         thank       5
#  1      recorded       7
#4 0         thank       5
```

If you only want to count words once then drop_duplicates:

```
df1.drop_duplicates('word').points.sum()
#12
```

---

#### Setup Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'transcript': 
                   ['thank you for calling my name is Tiffany and we want to let you know this call is recorded',
                    'Maggie',
                    'through the time',
                    'that you can find I have a question about a claim and our contact is',
                    'three to like even your box box and thank you for your help']})
```